# Type annotations for *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm trying out Python's type annotations with abstract base classes to write some interfaces. Is there a way to annotate the possible types of `*args` and `**kwargs`?

For example, how would one express that the sensible arguments to a function are either an `int` or two `int`s? `type(args)` gives `Tuple` so my guess was to annotate the type as `Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int]]`, but this doesn't work.

```
from typing import Union, Tuple

def foo(*args: Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int]]):
    try:
        i, j = args
        return i + j
    except ValueError:
        assert len(args) == 1
        i = args[0]
        return i

# ok
print(foo((1,)))
print(foo((1, 2)))
# mypy does not like this
print(foo(1))
print(foo(1, 2))
```

Error messages from mypy:

```
t.py: note: In function "foo":
t.py:6: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("tuple" and "Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int]]")
t.py: note: At top level:
t.py:12: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int]]"
t.py:14: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int]]"
t.py:15: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int]]"
t.py:15: error: Argument 2 to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int]]"
```

It makes sense that mypy doesn't like this for the function call because it expects there to be a `tuple` in the call itself. The addition after unpacking also gives a typing error that I don't understand.

How does one annotate the sensible types for `*args` and `**kwargs`?

Answer (score 516, accepted):

For variable positional arguments (`*args`) and variable keyword arguments (`**kw`) you only need to specify the expected value for *one* such argument.

From the [*Arbitrary argument lists and default argument values* section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values) of the *Type Hints* PEP:

> Arbitrary argument lists can as well be type annotated, so that the definition:
>
> ```
> def foo(*args: str, **kwds: int): ...
> ```
>
> is acceptable and it means that, e.g., all of the following represent function calls with valid types of arguments:
>
> ```
> foo('a', 'b', 'c')
> foo(x=1, y=2)
> foo('', z=0)
> ```

So you'd want to specify your method like this:

```
def foo(*args: int):
```

However, if your function can only accept either one or two integer values, you should not use `*args` at all, use one explicit positional argument and a second keyword argument:

```
def foo(first: int, second: Optional[int] = None):
```

Now your function is actually limited to one or two arguments, and both must be integers if specified. `*args` *always* means 0 or more, and can't be limited by type hints to a more specific range.

Comment: Just curious, why add the `Optional`? Did something change about Python or did you change your mind? Is it still not strictly necessary due to the `None` default?

Comment: @Praxeolitic yes, in practice the automatic, implied `Optional` annotation when you use `None` as a default value made certain usecases harder and that is now being removed from the PEP.

Comment: [Here is a link discussing this](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/275) for those interested. It certainly does sound like explicit `Optional` is going to be required in the future.

Comment: This is actually not supported for Callable: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5876

Comment: @ShitalShah: that’s not really what that issue is about. `Callable` doesn’t support *any* mention of a type hint for `*args` or `**kwargs` **full stop**. That specific issue is about marking up callables that accept specific arguments *plus an arbitrary number of others*, and so use `*args: Any, **kwargs: Any`, a very specific type hint for the two catch-alls. For cases where you set `*args` and / or `**kwargs` to something more specific you can use a `Protocol`.

Comment: Could it be cleaner to use [`@overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) on `foo` so that the two valid signatures are `foo(first: int)` and `foo(first: int, second: int)`, leaving the real signature as `foo(first, second=None)`? Or is just a matter of preference?

Comment: @wjandrea overloads won’t really help here; use overloads to aid the type checker when the combination of arguments alters what is being returned; e.g. `foo(1)` returns a string but `foo(1, 2)` produces an int, etc.

Answer (score 107):

## 2022 Update

The mypy team [added](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/13471) support for `Unpack`, this is available since [Mypy 0.981](https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2022/09/mypy-0981-released.html) or higher.

**Attention!** Although this feature is complete, `Unpack[...]` is still considered experimental, so you will need to use `--enable-incomplete-features` to enable it.

You can use this feature as follows:

```py
from typing import TypedDict
from typing_extensions import Unpack


class RequestParams(TypedDict):
    url: str
    allow_redirects: bool


def request(**kwargs: Unpack[RequestParams]) -> None:
    ...
```

If you call the `request` function with the arguments defined in the TypedDict, you won't get any errors:

```py
# OK
request(url="https://example.com", allow_redirects=True)
```

If you forget to pass an argument, mypy will let you know now

```py
# error: Missing named argument "allow_redirects" for "request"  [call-arg]
request(url="https://example.com")
```

You can also make the fields non-required by adding `total=False` to the TypedDict:

```py
class RequestParams(TypedDict, total=False):
    url: str
    allow_redirects: bool

# OK
request(url="https://example.com")
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Required` and `NotRequired` annotations to control whether a keyword argument is required or not:

```py
from typing import TypedDict
from typing_extensions import Unpack, NotRequired


class RequestParams(TypedDict):
    url: str
    allow_redirects: NotRequired[bool]

def request(**kwargs: Unpack[RequestParams]) -> None:
    ...

# OK
request(url="https://example.com", allow_redirects=True)
```

### Old answer below:

While you can annotate variadic arguments with a type, I don't find it very useful because it assumes that all arguments are of the same type.

The proper type annotation of `*args` and `**kwargs` that allows specifying each variadic argument separately is not supported by mypy yet. There is a proposal for adding an `Expand` helper on `mypy_extensions` module, it would work like this:

```
class Options(TypedDict):
    timeout: int
    alternative: str
    on_error: Callable[[int], None]
    on_timeout: Callable[[], None]
    ...

def fun(x: int, *, **options: Expand[Options]) -> None:
    ...
```

The [GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4441) was opened on January 2018 but it's still not closed. Note that while the issue is about `**kwargs`, the `Expand` syntax will likely be used for `*args` as well.

Comment: According to https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3002#issuecomment-1046100462 the new syntax is `**options: Unpack[Options]` and works in Pylance (but not yet mypy)

Comment: Great. If the answer is: `# type: ignore[no-untyped-def]`, then that is the answer!

Comment: this is now part of python 3.12

Answer (score 55):

The easiest way to do this -- without changing your function signature -- is using [`@overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)

First, some background.  You cannot annotate the type of `*args` as a whole, only the type of the items in `args`.  So you can't say that `*args` is `Tuple[int, int]` you can only say that the type of each item within `*args` is `int`.  That means that you can't put a limit on the length of `*args` or use a different type for each item.

To solve this you can consider changing the signature of your function to give it named arguments, each with their own type annotation, but if want (or need) to keep your function using `*args`, you can get mypy to work using `@overload`:

```
from typing import overload

@overload
def foo(arg1: int, arg2: int) -> int:
    ...

@overload
def foo(arg: int) -> int:
    ...

def foo(*args):
    try:
        i, j = args
        return i + j
    except ValueError:
        assert len(args) == 1
        i = args[0]
        return i

print(foo(1))
print(foo(1, 2))
```

Note that you do not add `@overload` or type annotations to the actual implementation, which must come last.

You can also use this to vary the returned result in a way that makes explicit which argument types correspond with which return type. e.g.:

```
from typing import Tuple, overload

@overload
def foo(arg1: int, arg2: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    ...

@overload
def foo(arg: int) -> int:
    ...

def foo(*args):
    try:
        i, j = args
        return j, i
    except ValueError:
        assert len(args) == 1
        i = args[0]
        return i

print(foo(1))
print(foo(1, 2))
```

Comment: I like this answer because it addresses the more general case. Looking back, I should not have used `(type1)` vs `(type1, type1)` function calls as my example. Maybe `(type1)` vs `(type2, type1)` would have been a better example and shows why I like this answer. This also allows differing return types. However, in the special case where you only have one return type and your `*args` and `*kwargs` are all the same type, the technique in Martjin's answer makes more sense so both answers are useful.

Comment: Using `*args` where there is a maximum number of arguments (2 here) is *still wrong* however.

Comment: So, yes, it's good to know about `@overload`, but it is the wrong tool *for this specific job*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why is `*args` necessarily wrong here? If the expected calls were `(type1)` vs `(type2, type1)`, then the number of arguments is variable and there isn't an appropriate default for the trailing argument. Why is it important that there's a max?

Comment: `*args` is really there for *zero or more*, uncapped, homogenous arguments, *or* for 'passing these along untouched' catch-alls. You have one required argument and one optional. That's totally different and is normally handled by giving the second argument a sentinel default value to detect that is was omitted.

Comment: Using `*args` where the cardinality is *at least n, at most m* where *n* is greater than 0 breaks the self-documenting nature and convention, whilst keyword arguments for optionals has a very long precedent in Python.

Comment: After looking at the PEP, this clearly isn't the intended use of @overload. While this answer shows an interesting way to individually annotate the types of `*args`, an even better answer to the question is that this isn't something that should be done at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm convinced on `*args` but what about `**kwargs`? It seems like it could be consistent with Python style to annotate individual types for `**kwargs` but there just isn't a way to do that. Would you agree?

Comment: @Praxeolitic: in Python 3, `**kwargs` is *mostly* used for passing on arguments to another call. But yes, that you can't annotate the values is.. unhelpful sometimes. The PEP is still in flux, the community is hashing out better ways of specifying complex cases as we discover them. See the [extensive discussion around decorators](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3157) (follow all the referenced issues) for example.

Comment: This is still the only answer that completely addresses the original question "Is there a way to annotate the *possible* types of *args and **kwargs", emphasis on "possible".  I'm not sure why I'm getting down-voted for what is the obvious correct answer.  The example was fabricated, but the intent was clear: the OP wanted to explicitly describe the possible signatures of the function `foo`.

Comment: At least in MyPy, one is encouraged to use the overloads rather than the direct call. Thus, the user is discouraged from passing in fewer or more positional arguments than necessary. This seems to be a standard, as it works in PyCharm as well. This solution allows multiple heterogenous overloads sharing a common base implementation but with non-runtime validation, and would therefore be what I consider the best solution. It may be a solution to implementing something that's considered non-Pythonic, but that's a secondary issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you wrote: "You have one required argument and one optional. That's totally different and is normally handled by giving the second argument a sentinel default value to detect that is was omitted."

I agree that a keyword argument would have been more clear, but even in that case you would still need to use `@overload` to properly type this function if the type of result or the first arg varied depending on the existence of the second argument.  e.g.  if the valid type signatures were `(int) -> int` and `(int, int) -> float`

Comment: @chadrik that’s the actual use-case for `@overload`, which is orthogonal to the issue discussed here. Put differently, it doesn't matter that the argument count varies, you also need `@overload` for `(int) -> int` vs `(float) -> float`, or `(bytes, int) -> bytes` vs `(str, int) -> str`, etc.

Comment: `@overload` is required when mimicking _functional polymorphism_. **Python does not natively support functional polymorphism.** If you `def` a function with multiple signatures, the last function `def`'d overrides (redefines) the previous ones. Python mimics functional polymorphism with _optional positional/keyword arguments_ (which coincidentally C++ does not support). Overloads are used when (1) typing ported C/C++ polymorphic functions, or (2) consistency must be maintained between types and their arity from parameters to return types. You have limited `*args` to 2 arguments instead of any.

Comment: @A.Hendry the ability to edit another user's post is meant to fix or update examples,  typos, etc.  You've just dumped your opinion into my opening paragraph.  Please leave your opinions in the comments.

Comment: @chadrik Fair enough; apologies for that. However, thank you for updating your answer: I don't think it was correct in saying "The correct way to do this is....". Your answer is only one way to get the type checking to work; there are others. I wouldn't have jumped straight to using `@overload`, but I will countenance that that is my opinion. Most importantly, in this case, I think it was important to clarify that this is "a" way to do this in order to avoid arguments in the community.

Comment: This will mistyped: it will fail  when calling arguments by name

Answer (score 28):

As a short addition to the previous answer, if you're trying to use mypy on Python 2 files and need to use comments to add types instead of annotations, you need to prefix the types for `args` and `kwargs` with `*` and `**` respectively:

```
def foo(param, *args, **kwargs):
    # type: (bool, *str, **int) -> None
    pass
```

This is treated by mypy as being the same as the below, Python 3.5 version of `foo`:

```
def foo(param: bool, *args: str, **kwargs: int) -> None:
    pass
```

Comment: This page now has multiple answers. Could you please mention, explicitly, which previous answer?

Answer (score 10):

> *I'm trying out Python's type annotations with abstract base classes to write some interfaces. Is there a way to annotate the possible types of* `*args` *and* `**kwargs`...*How does one annotate the sensible types for* `*args` *and* `**kwargs`

There are two general usage categories when it comes to type hinting:

1. **Writing your own code** (*which you can edit and change*)
2. **Using 3rd party code** (*which you can't edit, or is hard to change*)

Most users have some combo of both.

The answer depends on whether your `*args` and `**kwargs` have **homogeneous** types (i.e. all of the same type) or **heterogenous** types (i.e. different types), as well as whether there is a *fixed number* of them or a *variable/indeterminate number* of them (the term used here is fixed vs. variable [**arity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity))

`*args` and `**kwargs` have sometimes been used in what I'm loosely calling a "*Python-specific design pattern*" (see below). It is important to understand when this is being done because it affects the way you should type hint.

Best practice, always, is to *stand on the shoulders of giants*:

- I highly recommend reading and studying the [`typeshed` `.pyi` stubs](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/8a47a28e768c577385d6232d4afea496b60403e7/stdlib), especially for the standard library, to learn how developers have typed these things in the wild.

For those who want to see a HOW-TO come to life, please consider upvoting the following PRs:

- [Proposal: Convert the `typing`-module PEPs into a series of HOWTOs](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91533)
- [Document Structure and Wishlist](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/845)

---

#### Case 1: (*Writing Your Own Code*)

##### `*args`

(a) **Operating on a Variable Number of Homogeneous Arguments**

The first reason `*args` is used is to write a function that has to work on ***a variable (indeterminate) number of homogoeneous arguments***

Example: *summing numbers, accepting command line arguments, etc.*

In these cases, all `*args` are **homogeneous** (i.e. all the same type).

Example: *In the first case, all arguments are `int`s or `float`s; In the second case, all arguments are `str`s.*

It is also possible to use `Union`s, `TypeAlias`s, `Generic`s, and `Protocol`s as the type for `*args`.

I claim (without proof) that operating on an indeterminate number of homogeneous arguments was the first reason `*args` was introduced into the Python language.

Consequently, [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values) supports providing `*args` a homogeneous type.

> **Note:**
>
> Using `*args` is done much less often than specifying parameters explicitly
> (i.e. *logically, your code base will have many more functions that don't use* `*args` *than do*). Using `*args` for homogeneous types is normally done [to avoid requiring users
> to put arguments into a
> container](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#using-the-python-args-variable-in-function-definitions)
> before passing them to the function.
>
> **It is [recommended to type parameters
> explicitly](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/#intended-usage) wherever
> possible.**
>
> - If for nothing else, you would normally be documenting each argument with its type in a docstring anyway (*not
>   documenting is a quick way to make others not want to use your code,
>   including your future self.*)
>
> Note also that `args` is a *tuple* because the **unpacking operator (`*`)** [returns a tuple](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#using-the-python-args-variable-in-function-definitions), so note that you can't mutate `args` directly (You would have to pull the mutable object out of `args`).

(b) **Writing Decorators and Closures**

The second place where `*args` will pop up is in decorators. For this, using [`ParamSpec`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) as described in `PEP 612` is the way to go.

(c) **Top-Level Functions that Call Helpers**

This is the "*Python-specific design pattern*" I alluded to. For `Python >= 3.11`, [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple) show examples where you can use `TypeVarTuple` to type this so the type information is preserved between calls.

- Using `*args` this way is typically done to reduce the amount of code to write, esp. when the arguments between multiple functions are the same
- It has also been used to "swallow up" a variable number of arguments through tuple unpacking that may not be needed in the next function

Here, items in `*args` have *heterogenous* types, and possibly a variable number of them, **both of which can be problematic**.

***The Python typing ecosystem does not have a way to specify heterogenous `*args`.*** <sup>1</sup>

Before the advent of type checking, developers would need to check the type of individual arguments in `*args` (with `assert`, `isinstance`, etc.) if they needed to do something differently depending on the type:

Examples:

- You need to print passed `str`s, but sum the passed `int`s

Thankfully, the `mypy` developers included [type inference](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#local-type-inference) and [type narrowing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html) to `mypy` to support these kinds of situations. (*Also, existing code bases don't need to change much if they were already using `assert`, `isintance`, etc., to determine the types of the items in `*args`*)

Consequently, in this case you would do the following:

- [Give `*args` the type `object`](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/best_practices.html#using-any-and-object) so its elements can be any type, and
- use [type narrowing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html) where needed with `assert ... is (not) None`, `isinstance`, `issubclass`, etc., to determine the types of individual items in `*args`

---

> ###### <sup>1</sup> Warning:
>
> For `Python >= 3.11`, `*args` can be typed with
> `TypeVarTuple`, but this is [meant to be used when type hinting
> *variadic generics*](https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/1258). It ***should not*** be used for typing `*args` in the general
> case.
>
> `TypeVarTuple` was primarily introduced to help type hint `numpy`
> arrays, `tensorflow` tensors, and similar data structures, but for `Python >= 3.11`, it can be used to preserve type information between calls for [top-level functions calling helpers](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple) as stated before.
>
> Functions that process heterogenous `*args` (not just pass them through) must still [type
> narrow](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html) to
> determine the types of individual items.
>
> For `Python <3.11`, `TypeVarTuple` can be accessed through
> [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/), but to date there is only provisional support for it through `pyright` (not `mypy`). Also, `PEP 646` includes a section on using [`*args` as a Type Variable
> Tuple](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#args-as-a-type-variable-tuple).

---

##### `**kwargs`

(a) **Operating on a Variable Number of Homogeneous Arguments**

`PEP 484` supports typing all *values* of the `**kwargs` dictionary as a **homogeneous** type. All *keys* are automatically `str`s.

Like `*args`, it is also possible to use `Union`s, `TypeAlias`s, `Generic`s, and `Protocol`s as the type for `*kwargs`.

I've not found a compelling use case for processing a *homogeneous* set of named arguments using `**kwargs`.

(b) **Writing Decorators and Closures**

Again, I would point you to [`ParamSpec`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) as described in `PEP 612`.

(c) **Top-Level Functions that Call Helpers**

This is also the "*Python-specific design pattern*" I alluded to.

For a finite set of heterogeneous keyword types, you can use `TypedDict` and `Unpack` if [PEP 692](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/) is approved.

However, the same things for `*args` applies here:

- It is best to explicitly type out your keyword arguments
- If your types are heterogenous and of unknown size, type hint with `object` and type narrow in the function body

#### Case 2: (3rd Party Code)

This ultimately amounts to following the guidelines for the part `(c)`s in `Case 1`.

---

#### Outtro

##### Static Type Checkers

The answer to your question also depends on the static type checker you use. To date (and to my knowledge), your choices for static type checker include:

- `mypy`: Python's de facto static type checker
- `pyright`: Microsoft's static type checker
- `pyre`: Facebook/Instagram's static type checker
- `pytype`: Google's static type checker

I personally have only ever used `mypy` and `pyright`. For these, the [`mypy` playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8) and [`pyright` playground](https://pyright-playground.decorator-factory.su/?issue=microsoft/pyright/2662) are great places to test out type hinting your code.

##### Interfaces

ABCs, like descriptors and metaclasses, are tools for building frameworks (1). If there's a chance you could be turning your API from a "consenting adults" Python syntax into a "bondage-and-discipline" syntax (to [borrow a phrase from Raymond Hettinger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miGolgp9xq8)), consider [YAGNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

That said (preaching aside), when writing interfaces, it's important to consider whether you should use `Protocol`s or `ABC`s.

###### Protocols

In OOP, a **protocol** is an informal interface, defined only in documentation and not in code (see [this review article of Fluent Python, Ch. 11, by Luciano Ramalho](https://dgkim5360.github.io/blog/python/2017/07/duck-typing-vs-goose-typing-pythonic-interfaces/)). Python adopted this concept from Smalltalk, where a protocol was an interface seen as a set of methods to fulfill. In Python, this is achieved by implementing specific dunder methods, which is described in the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-generic-types) and I touch upon briefly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874287/python-data-model-type-protocols-magic-methods).

Protocols implement what is called **structural subtyping**. In this paradigm, _a subtype is determined by its structure, i.e. behavior), as opposed to **nominal subtyping** (*i.e. a subtype is determined by its inheritance tree*). Structural subtyping is also called [**static duck typing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), as compared to traditional (dynamic) duck typing. (The term is thanks to Alex Martelli.)

Other classes don't need to subclass to adhere to a protocol: they just need to implement specific dunder methods. With type hinting, [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) in Python 3.8 introduced a way to formalize the protocol concept. Now, you can create a class that inherits from `Protocol` and define any functions you want in it. So long as another class implements those functions, it's considered to adhere to that `Protocol`.

###### ABCs

Abstract base classes complement duck-typing and are helpful when you run into situations like:

```py
class Artist:
    def draw(self): ...

class Gunslinger:
    def draw(self): ...

class Lottery:
    def draw(self): ...
```

Here, the fact that these classes all implement a `draw()` might doesn't necessarily mean these objects are interchangeable (again, see Fluent Python, Ch. 11, by Luciano Ramalho)! An ABC gives you the ability to make a clear declaration of intent. Also, you can create a *virtual subclass* by `register`ing the class so you don't have to subclass from it (in this sense, you are following the GoF principle of "favoring composition over inheritance" by not tying yourself directly to the ABC).

Raymond Hettinger gives an excellent talk on ABCs in the collections module in his [PyCon 2019 Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_ipdVNSFlo).

Also, Alex Martelli called ABCs **goose typing**. You can subclass many of the classes in `collections.abc`, implement only a few methods, and have classes behave like the builtin Python protocols implemented with dunder methods.

[image: The Python Typing Paradigm]

Luciano Ramalho gives an excellent talk on this and its relationship to the typing ecosystem in his [PyCon 2021 Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDDCKwP7QgQ).

#### Incorrect Approaches

##### `@overload`

`@overload` is designed to be used to mimic [functional polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

- Python does not natively support functional polymorphism (C++ and several other languages do).

  - If you `def` a function with multiple signatures, the last function `def`'d overrides (redefines) the previous ones.

```py
def func(a: int, b: str, c: bool) -> str:
    print(f'{a}, {b}, {c}')

def func(a: int, b: bool) -> str:
    print(f'{a}, {b}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func(1, '2', True)  # Error: `func()` takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Python mimics functional polymorphism with *optional positional/keyword arguments* (coincidentally, C++ does not support keywrod arguments).

Overloads are to be used when

- (1) typing ported C/C++ polymorphic functions, or
- (2) type consistency must be maintained between depending on types used in a function call

Please see [Adam Johnson's blog post "Python Type Hints - How to Use `@overload`](https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/05/29/python-type-hints-how-to-use-overload/).

#### References

(1) Ramalho, Luciano. Fluent Python (p. 320). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 9):

In some cases the content of **kwargs can be a variety of types.

This seems to work for me:

```py
from typing import Any

def testfunc(**kwargs: Any) -> None:
    print(kwargs)
```

or

```py
from typing import Any, Optional

def testfunc(**kwargs: Optional[Any]) -> None:
    print(kwargs)
```

In the case where you feel the need to constrain the types in `**kwargs` I suggest creating a struct-like object and add the typing there.  This can be done with dataclasses, or pydantic.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyTypedKwargs:
   expected_variable: str
   other_expected_variable: int


def testfunc(expectedargs: MyTypedKwargs) -> None:
    pass
```

Comment: This essentially disables type checking, doesn't it? That's like leaving out the annotation for `kwargs` altogether.

Comment: `**kwargs` is by design and technically can be anything.  If you know what you're getting I suggest defining that as a typed argument.  The advantage here is that for cases where using `**kwargs` is acceptable/expected, in ides/tools, like pycharm, is it won't give you a notification that the type is incorrect.

Comment: I partially disagree. I think there are situations where it's reasonable to constrain types for **kwargs or *args. But I also see that type checking and **kwargs doesn't go together very well (at least for current Python versions). Maybe you want to add this to your answer to better addresse the OPs question.

Comment: Yeah, there may be a usecase for typing kwargs, but I would lean toward making your inputs clearer instead of lumping them in to kwargs.

Comment: It's a good practice to avoid using `Any` because it disables type checking completely. Instead you can use `object` and then `# type: ignore` wherever you expand kwargs.

Answer (score 7):

If one wants to describe specific named arguments expected in kwargs, one can instead pass in a TypedDict(which defines required and optional parameters). Optional parameters are what were the kwargs.
Note: [TypedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) is in python >= 3.8
See this example:

```
import typing

class RequiredProps(typing.TypedDict):
    # all of these must be present
    a: int
    b: str

class OptionalProps(typing.TypedDict, total=False):
    # these can be included or they can be omitted
    c: int
    d: int

class ReqAndOptional(RequiredProps, OptionalProps):
    pass

def hi(req_and_optional: ReqAndOptional):
    print(req_and_optional)
```

Comment: sometimes you get so wrapped up in one way of doing something you forget the simple way. thanks for this.

Comment: This is so good. +1

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What part about it doesn't work? It depends upon using python 3.8 or later. Are you talking about an ide not implementing typeddict support?

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
```

### Motivation

This is the answer given by Chris in the comments, I did not find consensus within 5 minutes of scanning the answers, and it was not that relevant for me to get the typing correct of this default Python syntax. Still I do value `mypy` on my own code, so this was, timewise, an acceptable compromise for me. Perhaps it helps someone.