# How to annotate variadic parameters in Python using typing annotations?

Tags: python, typing, pep

How to annotate parameters of the variadic function?

Example:

```
def foo(*args):  # Each arg expected to be of type T
    ...
```

Are there any typing annotations for that?

Comment: Related question: in order to type hint a `Callable` type like this refer to [Python type hint for Callable with variable number of str/same type arguments? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658879/python-type-hint-for-callable-with-variable-number-of-str-same-type-arguments) ■ also possible duplicate of [python - Type annotations for *args and **kwargs - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031928/type-annotations-for-args-and-kwargs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

Basically `args` treated as a homogeneous tuple and `kwds` as a dictionary.
You simply annotate a type being expected for each element value.

### Explanation

Explanation arrives from [quote](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values) of the PEP-484:

> In the body of function foo, the type of variable args is deduced as `Tuple[str, ...]` and the type of variable kwds is `Dict[str, int]`.

So there is no need to annotate args as whole homogeneous typed tuple but one can reduce `Tuple[T, ...]` to just type `T`.

Same true for the keyword arguments as they deduced as `Dict[str, T]`

#### About ellipsis in the tuple annotation

In python documentation there is no much information about the usage of the `...` a.k.a [`Ellipsis`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) but PEP-484 does mention various usages of the ellipsis in typing annotations like for omitting some type annotations or default values but most interestingly there is a [quote](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-typing-module) saying:

> Tuple, used by listing the element types, for example `Tuple[int, int, str]`. The empty tuple can be typed as `Tuple[()]`. Arbitrary-length
> homogeneous tuples can be expressed using one type and ellipsis, for
> example `Tuple[int, ...]`. (The `...` here are part of the syntax, a
> literal ellipsis.)

So if you omit asterisk to force passing arguments as a single tuple you need keep full annotation:

```
def foo(args: Tuple[T, ...]):
    ...
```

#### About various types in a homogeneous tuple

Since homogeneous tuple means all of its elements must be of the same type then if you wish to allow several types just use a `Union` or even use a type alias for better readability:

```
MyArg = Union[int, str, bool]

def foo(*args: MyArg):
    ...
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the right way? According to [the pep](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values) varargs aren't annotated as `Tuple`, but rather like `def foo(*args: str):` (and not `Tuple[str]`). So, wouldn't your annotation mean that your function accepts a variable number of homogeneous tuples?

Comment: Hm… I probably missed that because I was looking for ellipsis as I remembered there was a way involving it. Also, I find no problems with annotating it as `Tuple` and within a function, it does pass test `isinstance(args, tuple)`. Please, note without `*` asterisk. I believe `*args: T` is a shorthand for `*args: Tuple[T, ...]` so I observe no troubles with that.

Comment: Well, @Aran-Fey PyCharm and IDEA of today do not understand full syntax correctly and recognize correctly the shorter version as you mentioned.

Comment: @kuza you accepted your answer to your own question, but the problem is that it's incorrect.

Comment: Well, I did correct myself after an update, quoting PEP 484. Perhaps it was tl;dr for you? I will try shrinking my answer to the point.

Answer (score 7):

If each argument has a `TheType` type - annotate it as specified in [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values):

```
def foo(*args: TheType):
    ...
```

Do not use: <s>`def foo(*args: Tuple[TheType]):`</s>, because specifying `Tuple[TheType]` means it's a single-element tuple - with one `TheType` element, which is not what variadic args are intended to serve.

Comment: Well, specifying `Tuple[TheType]` actually means that you expect tuples of type `TheType` as your variable arguments. _Per se_ `args` is a homogeneous tuple already and the asterisk simply expands it. This is why you only left to annotate _the type_.

Comment: @kuza That is incorrect. What you mean is `Tuple[TheType, ...]`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple).
Plain `Tuple[TheType]` refers to a non-variadic tuple with one element of type `TheType`.