# Python type hint for Callable with variable number of str/same type arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

How can I specify one type for all of these callables:

```
a(str)
b(str, str)
c(str, str, str)
d(str, str, str, str
```

I found that I can specify `Callable[..., None]` in general way but how to specify with details that all arguments will be str without doing ugly syntax `Union[Callable[[str], None], Callable[[str, str], None, __more_like_this__]`. Is it other method to do it? Can I do it with use typing?

Comment: So what's ugly about it? I don't see what you want to change about it that would make it less "ugly"

Comment: You have four functions, each with a very *specific*, *different* type. A union is the only way to go. (`a`, for example, does not belong to the type of functions that can take 1-4 `str` arguments; it belongs to the type of functions that accepts *exactly* one argument.)

Comment: @chepner Probably you have right - no support for *args or not need support for it.

Comment: I've tried to provide an answer along the lines of my comment; drop a comment if you think I'm missing a point that should be addressed (like, maybe a third type `t3` that you think should be considered).

Comment: Do you want to type hint 1-4 ``str`` arguments, or *any* number of ``str`` arguments?

Answer (score 18):

You could use a [callback protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocols.html#callback-protocols) to specify a function type with variadic string arguments:

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol


class Callback(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, *args: str) -> None: ...
```

And use it like this:

```
def handler(cb: Callback) -> None:
    cb('a', 'b', 'c')

def callback(*args: str) -> None:
    pass

handler(callback)
```

Note that the callback has to take variadic arguments, e.g. this won't work:

```
def callback(a: str, b: str) -> None:
    pass
```

Protocols were added in Python 3.8 to the standard library [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) module, so if you want to use them on Python 3.5-3.7, you will need to install the [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module from PyPI.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is the union of 4 distinct types.

```
t1 = Union[
 Callable[[str],Any],
 Callable[[str,str],Any],
 Callable[[str,str,str],Any],
 Callable[[str,str,str,str],Any],
]
```

Constrast that with the type of function that can accept 1 to 4 arguments:

```
t2 = Callable[[str,Optional[str],Optional[str],Optional[str]],Any]
```

A function like

```
def foo(x: str, y:str):
```

does not belong to the second type above. If I say I need a function of type `t2`, you don't know how many arguments I might try to pass. I could give you `foo`, but then you might try to pass 3 arguments, or only 1, and get a `TypeError`.

If you ask for a function of type `t1`, it's OK for me to give you `foo`. `t1` does *not* promise that all values in `t1` can more or less than exactly 3 arguments; it only includes values that *do*.