# How to correctly add type hints to a decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting

I'm currently writing and learning about decorators (with and without arguments). Here is an example of a decorator with one argument that redirects the output of a function to a log file. The code works, but my questions are the following:

1. What is the correct way to use type hints when dealing with decorators?
2. Are decorators supposed to have docstrings? If so, in my example, is the docstring correct/complete?

Thank you in advance!

```
def redirect_output(log_file):
    """
    Decorator to redirect the stdout written output of a function to a specified
        log file.
    Args:
        log_file (str): The path to the log file where the output will be redirected.
    """

    def redirect_output_decorator(func):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def redirect_output_wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
            output = StringIO()

            with redirect_stdout(output):
                func(*args, **kwargs)

            output_lines = output.getvalue().splitlines()

            if output_lines:
                file_logger("Output from {}: ".format(func.__name__), log_file)

                for line in output_lines:
                    file_logger(line, log_file, with_date=False)

        return redirect_output_wrapper

    return redirect_output_decorator
```

Comment: It's never a bad idea to have docstrings especially in functions. In terms of completeness/correctness, that is somewhat subjective but I believe that first docstring is good. Now there is a `Callable` type hint available and you could use that to specify the input and return of your decorators etc. Is it needed? probably not since your functions could take any arguments and you would be using `typing.Any` a lot. That isn't very descriptive. So all I could suggest is, have some of those neat `>>> ...` examples in your docstring so people can see how to use them

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy thanks for the answer. Could you show me an example on how to use Callable? Already tried it but the Mypy type checker keeps sending me warnings.

Comment: `main_decorator_output = typing.Callable[[typing.Callable], typing.Callable[..., typing.Any]]` is the type that `redirect_output` returns. So `def redirect_output(log_file) -> main_decorator_output`. Simply put, it takes a function and returns: a function which takes an arbitrary set of params and returns something. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable. You could also decorate the inner part like `def redirect_output_decorator(func: typing.Callable) -> typing.Callable[..., typing.Any]`

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy thank you so much! Do you have any idea on how the wrapper should be type hinted?

Comment: np. But `typing.Callable[..., typing.Any]` is the type of `redirect_output_wrapper` which I assume is the wrapper you are referring to. This line `def redirect_output_decorator(func: typing.Callable) -> typing.Callable[..., typing.Any]` is already providing the type hint for that wrapper since it is the return value. If you want annotations for `*args` and `**kwargs` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031928/type-annotations-for-args-and-kwargs

Comment: Yeah, i was asking about ```*args``` and ```**kwargs```, sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the answers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParamSpec` is a solution to this problem.
Here is the code example
in its [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec).

```py
from typing import TypeVar, ParamSpec
import logging

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

def add_logging(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    '''A type-safe decorator to add logging to a function.'''
    def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        logging.info(f'{f.__name__} was called')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

It is officially supported after Python 3.10, but is also supported by importing from `typing_extensions`(https://github.com/python/typing_extensions) for python version greater than 3.7