# Python Data Model, Type Protocols, & Magic Methods

Tags: python, magic-methods, datamodel

Is there a "mind map", UML diagram, graphic, or some solid reference for the different python types and the magic methods they must implement?

I'm using Python 3.8. The [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-generic-types) and [built-in types docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) docs are very terse and it would help me to see a high-level overview of the different protocols that exist for different types in python (I've "learned" (read?) that, e.g., to implement an "immutable-like" object, you must adhere to the `Immutable Protocol` in python, which means you must implement `__len__` and `__getitem__`. To make it "mutable-like", you must further add `__setitem__` and `__delitem__`).

I don't see (from as far as I've searched) the word "protocol" being used in the python docs, and the closest good description seems to come from the [collections abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) module. However, as a newcomer, I'm not sure if `collections.abc` is something else entirely, or if the information provided there applies to the python builtin types (i.e. `list`, `tuple`, `dict`, etc.; particularly becuase the `collections.abc` docs states it "provid[es] alternatives to Python’s general purpose built-in containers, dict, list, set, and tuple" and second because I wouldn't think to go to the `collections` module if I wanted to learn about the default builtins from the python language itself).

Does anyone have a solid resource? It would be helpful if the information were in a kind of inheritance relationship format so that info doesn't get repeated. For instance, in my example above, rather than say that a `mutable-like` object implements `__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, and `__delitem__`, it would be easier for my puny brain to hold if it were "chunked" and the info was something like "a `mutable-like` object inherits from `immutable-like` and adds `__setitem__`, and `__delitem__`.

Are there any thoughts? I think this is a huge source of confusion for newcomers and many errors result from a misunderstanding of the data types in python.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Python Data Model]

Building a lot from [the glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html), this is the best I could do for now. I hope this question can be expanded by multiple answers from others.

### Definitions

- **Mutable:** an object *whose value can change* after instantiation
- **Immutable:** an object *whose value cannot change* after instantiation
- **Container:** an object containing references to other objects
- **Sequence:** a *finite ordered set* indexed by non-negative numbers
- **Mapping:** a *finite set* of objects indexed by *arbitrary index sets*
- **Callable:** types to with the function call operation can be applied
- **Number (`numbers`):** an *immutable* value supporting numeric operations
- **Range:** an *immutable* sequence of numbers
- **String:** an *immutable sequence* of characters accessed by *index*
- **Byte:** an *immutable sequence* of short integers
- **List (`[]`):** a *mutable sequence* of object references accessed by *index*
- **Dictionary (`{key: value}`):** a *mutable mapping* of object references accessed by *key*
- **Tuple (`()`):** an *immutable sequence* of object references accessed by *index*
- **Set (`{}`):** a *mutable* unordered collection of *unique and immutable* objects
- **Frozen Set:** an *immutable* and *hashable* collection of *unique and hashable* objects

### Types

- **Orderable/Comparable:** implements `__eq__()` and `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, `__ge__()`. For *containment checking* (i.e. use with `in`), implements `__contains__()` or is an `Iterable`
- **Iterable:** an object capable of returning its members one at a time
- **Iterator:** implements `__iter__()` (returns object) and `__next__()` (returns next item from container; raises `StopIteration` when complete)
- **Generator:** implements `__iter__()` (yields object) and `__next__()` (yields next item from container; raises `StopIteration` when complete)
- **Immutable Sequences:** implements `__hash__()`
- **Context Manageable:** implements `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` (to be used in a `with` statement)
- **Descriptor:** implements `__get__()`, `__set__()`, and/or `__delete__()`

### Overloaded Operations

- **Sequences:**

  - `+` is *concatentation*
  - `*` is *repetition*[2](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html)

[2](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) NOTE: *Repeated items in the sequence **are not copied**, but **referenced multiple times**. To make unique copies, use a list comprehension or generator expression.*

### Additional Comments

- The `built-in` types are all the `lower case` objects (e.g. `list`, `tuple`, `str`, etc.)
- All `Sequences` are `Iterables`
- For new immutables to be created from old ones, a new object must be created
- `Sets` and `Dicitionaries` also support comprehension
- `Bitwise Operations` can be used on `Sets` to implement set theoretic operations (i.e. Union, Intersection, Symmetric Difference, etc.)

### Conceptual Groupings of Sequence Types

1. Container/Flat Sequences

   - **Container Sequences:** can hold items of different types (`list`,
     `tuple`, `collections.deque`)
   - **Flat Sequences:** can only hold items of one type (`str`, `bytes`,
     `bytearray`, `memoryview`, `array.array`)
2. Mutable/Immutable Sequences

   - **Mutable Sequences:** `list`, `bytearray`, `array.array`, `collections.deque`, `memoryview`
   - **Immutable Sequences:** `tuple`, `str`, `bytes`

Another good reference is [Fluent Python, by Luciano Ramalho](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491946008)