# Inferring argument types from **args

Tags: python, python-typing

Let's say I have code like this:

```py
def a(n:int = 10, s:str = "")->int:
    return n 

def b(**args):
    return a(**args)
```

Is there any way to tell python that `b` takes one argument named `n` that is an integer and another `s` that is a string? In other words, is there a way to pass the typing through **dict?

Update: to be clear, I am looking for a general solution that would work for arbitrary number of arguments with arbitrary types. My goal is to follow the DRY principle when it comes to specifying argument types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type annotations for \*args and \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031928/type-annotations-for-args-and-kwargs)

Comment: `def foo(*args: str, **kwds: int):`

Comment: Not at all... I am looking for a general solution for half a dozen of variously typed arguments. I'll update the question.

Comment: If you know you want `n: int` and `s: str`, then add them to the signature. No reason to make `b` so generic. (What's the purpose of `b` if it does nothing *except* call `a`?)

Comment: @chepner I think OP gave us a minimal example to illustrate the question, removing anything not relevant to the question.

Comment: I think it removed things that *were* relevant, because `b` as defined makes no sense (might as well just write `b = a`).

Comment: There are cases when we need this kind of wrapping, e.g. converting an instance method to a callable, or writing a decorator, or some cases of delegation. I did try for a minimalistic example.

Comment: @chepner , "There is no way because using the language this way is not idiomatic" is an answer too. I am not sure I'll like it, but I will accept it. :)

Comment: It is implemented for `*args` (PEP for 3.11, but backport in `typing_extensions` exists): [pep](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/). For `**kwargs` - not yet, there was a huge discussion, there are plans to implement similar `Unpack` for `TypedDict` to support `**kwargs`, but it will take time, now there is no draft pep for this - we're waiting!

Comment: If you preserve the signature of inner function, you can use [this technique](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=fcb4ed5ff1a0beba23169ba329ba75a0) (gist mine), plus [`typing.Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate) if you need to change the signature. But it will require separate decorator for every updated function.

Comment: @SUTerliakov , your comments look like they are the answer... Could you post them as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old story, which was discussed for a long time. Here's `mypy` [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4441) related to this problem (still open since 2018), it is even mentioned in [PEP-589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/). Some steps were taken in right direction: python 3.11 introduced `Unpack` and allowed star unpacking in annotations - it was designed together with variadic generics support, see [PEP-646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) (backported to `typing_extensions`, but no `mypy` support yet AFAIC). But it works only for `*args`, `**kwargs` construction is still waiting.

However, it is possible with additional efforts. You can create your own decorator that can convince `mypy` that function has expected signature ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=fcb4ed5ff1a0beba23169ba329ba75a0)):

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar, cast

_C = TypeVar('_C', bound=Callable)

def preserve_sig(func: _C) -> Callable[[Callable], _C]:
    def wrapper(f: Callable) -> _C:
        return cast(_C, f)
    return wrapper

def f(x: int, y: str = 'foo') -> int:
    return 1

@preserve_sig(f)
def g(**kwargs: Any) -> int:
    return f(**kwargs)

g(x=1, y='bar')
g(z=0)  # E: Unexpected keyword argument "z" for "g"
```

You can even alter function signature, appending or prepending new arguments, with [PEP-612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=5b433d5295fa851fd8ebd65c4124247c):

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar, cast

_R = TypeVar('_R')
_P = ParamSpec('_P')


def alter_sig(func: Callable[_P, _R]) -> Callable[[Callable], Callable[Concatenate[int, _P], _R]]:
    
    def wrapper(f: Callable) -> Callable[Concatenate[int, _P], _R]:
        
        @wraps(f)
        def inner(num: int, *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs):
            print(num)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
            
        return inner
    
    return wrapper

def f(x: int, y: str = 'foo') -> int:
    return 1

@alter_sig(f)
def g(**kwargs: Any) -> int:
    return f(**kwargs)

g(1, x=1, y='bar')
g(1, 2, 'bar')
g(1, 2)
g(x=1, y='bar')  # E: Too few arguments for "g"
g(1, 'baz')  # E: Argument 2 to "g" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
g(z=0)  # E: Unexpected keyword argument "z" for "g"
```