# Type hint that methods in a subclass of requests.Session accept new parameters

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

This code runs fine, but mypy complains:

```
class NamePrintingSession(requests.Session):
    def request(self, method, url, name=None, **kwargs):
        print(name)
        return super().request(method, url, **kwargs)


nps = NamePrintingSession()
nps.get("http://www.google.com", name="wooo") # error: Unexpected keyword argument "name" for "get" of "Session"
```

I kind of understand WHY it fails: Althought the definition of `get()` in requests accepts `**kwargs`, the stubs have some sort of additional information, and that doesnt change just because `request()` in my derived class accepts an additional parameter.

Is it possible to type-hint the `get`, `post`, `delete`, etc methods in my subclass with the parameters from the parent class but add the `name` parameter? (preferably without explicitly re-stating every parameter and also keeping the documentation links intact)

Comment: Updated my code to show that `name` is optional. The derived get method allows additional parameters but is fine with having the same ones as the base version.

Comment: Look closer at `request` definition in stubs. It doesn't include a star, so call like `session.request('GET', uri, 'q=something')` is perfectly valid. This is incompatible with your definition ('q=something' will be assigned to wrong parameter).  However, overriding `get` or `post` this way is okay, because everything except `url` is kwonly in parent class.

Comment: Ok, I guess I could add `*args` to my request definition (before `name=`) and pass it to the parent method similarly, to ensure better compatibility. But I feel we're getting off topic here, because this doesn't help with my actual problem.

Comment: About preserving `**kwargs` signature, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72304369/inferring-argument-types-from-args/72329755#72329755). Decorator approach will work, you'll have to repeat all parameters only once.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the [`get`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/sessions.py#L591) method at *sessions.py* is the following

```
# sessions.py

class Session:
    ...

    def get(self, url, **kwargs):
        r"""Sends a GET request. Returns :class:`Response` object.

        :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
        :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
        :rtype: requests.Response
        """

        kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
```

So it uses the `request` method for its implementation, setting `GET` as a request method. Overriding the arguments of the `request` method changes only the typing behavior of the `request` method.

The base implementation allows any keyword argument as it defines `**kwargs`, but it also has an interface declared at the *sessions.pyi* file. `.pyi` files are called [stub files](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html) and are used to separate implementation from typing interfaces. If the implementation does not contain any typing hints, the IDE looks at the `.pyi` declaration.

As we can see, all possible keyword arguments of the `get` method are declared at *sessions.pyi*.

```
# sessions.pyi

class Session:
    ...

    def get(
        self,
        url: Text | bytes,
        params: _Params | None = ...,
        data: Any | None = ...,
        headers: Any | None = ...,
        cookies: Any | None = ...,
        files: Any | None = ...,
        auth: Any | None = ...,
        timeout: Any | None = ...,
        allow_redirects: bool = ...,
        proxies: Any | None = ...,
        hooks: Any | None = ...,
        stream: Any | None = ...,
        verify: Any | None = ...,
        cert: Any | None = ...,
        json: Any | None = ...,
    ) -> Response: ...
```

The issue appeared as the interface did not contain the `name` keyword argument.

So what is happening when we call the `get` method on the object of the `NamePrintingSession`?

- As the `NamePrintingSession` does not implement the `get` method, it will call the `get` method implementation of the `Session` class.
- As the `get` implementation at *sessions.py* does not contain typing hints, the IDE looks for `.pyi` file of the *sessions.py*, which should be *sessions.pyi*, and if any interface of `get` is found, then uses it. If the `get` method did not have an interface, any keyword arguments would be allowed because of the `**kwargs` of the base implementation.

To fix that issue, you can customize the implementation of the `get` method for the `NamePrintingSession` class. But this solution is not optimal if the `name` argument should not affect the request behavior. In other words, if the `name` is used only in the `request` method, then there is no reason to override the rest methods like

```
# customSession.py

import requests


class NamePrintingSession(requests.Session):
    def request(self, method, url, name=None, **kwargs):
        print(name)
        return super().request(method, url, **kwargs)

    def get(self, url, name=None, **kwargs):
        print(name)
        super().get(url, **kwargs)
```

Another solution is that you can create a stub file and declare a new interface for your `NamePrintingSession` class.
Suppose the file that contains the `NamePrintingSession` class is called `customSession.py`. Then you should create a file with the name `customSession.pyi` in the same directory.

```
# customSession.pyi

import requests


class NamePrintingSession(requests.Session):
    def request(self, method, url, name=None, **kwargs):
        ...

    def get(self, url, name=None, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Comment: Your second solution sounds like what I am after! although I guess I will have to repeat the parameters that I dont change to make it still check those? I’ll try it out..

Comment: Where does the `get` stub you provide come from? In [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stubs/requests/requests/sessions.pyi#L119=) (and so in `types-requests` package) it is defined with all keyword-only args except `url`. It is extremely important here, because without that star such override would be not allowed. Also please note that IDE != mypy.

Comment: @SUTerliakov, I copied it from `/snap/pycharm-professional/285/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/requests/requests/sessions.pyi`. They are very similar but it seems pycharm uses its own version.

Comment: The customSession.pyi approach works, but is it possible to get the param list from the superclass, so I dont have to repeat all the optional parameters? (data, headers etc) (just using **kwargs like in your answer makes it so that any keyword arguments are accepted)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to inherit function parameters from another one.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan funny, it's worth issue/PR, because this allows calls that raise on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Heavily inspired by [Artyom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515998/1591921) and combined with Unpack (only available in pyright atm, not yet in mypy), this is the best that can be done I think. But mostly I'll just use `self.request("GET", ...)` directly instead (because this solution still doesnt give proper code completion suggestions in vscode)

```
# mymodule.pyi

import requests
from typing import Any, Union
from typing_extensions import Unpack, TypedDict, NotRequired

class RequestArgs(TypedDict):
    name: NotRequired[str]
    params: NotRequired[Any]
    data: NotRequired[Any]
    headers: NotRequired[Any]
    cookies: NotRequired[Any]
    files: NotRequired[Any]
    auth: NotRequired[Any]
    timeout: NotRequired[Any]
    allow_redirects: NotRequired[bool]
    proxies: NotRequired[Any]
    hooks: NotRequired[Any]
    stream: NotRequired[Any]
    verify: NotRequired[bool]
    cert: NotRequired[Any]
    json: NotRequired[Any]

class NamePrintingSession(requests.Session):
    def get(self, url: Union[str, bytes], **kwargs: Unpack[RequestArgs]): ...
    def options(self, url: Union[str, bytes], **kwargs: Unpack[RequestArgs]): ...
    def head(self, url: Union[str, bytes], **kwargs: Unpack[RequestArgs]): ...
    def post(self, url: Union[str, bytes], **kwargs: Unpack[RequestArgs]): ...
    def put(self, url: Union[str, bytes], **kwargs: Unpack[RequestArgs]): ...
    def patch(self, url: Union[str, bytes], **kwargs: Unpack[RequestArgs]): ...
    def delete(self, url: Union[str, bytes], **kwargs: Unpack[RequestArgs]): ...
```