# Type hinting function with function argument

Tags: python, type-hinting

Consider the following function:

```
def test(data: np.ndarray, func, *args) -> np.ndarray:
    return func(data, args)
```

The func and args arguments are numpy function and arguments corresponding to it.
The question is, how do i annotate these two arguments with type hinting?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031928/type-annotations-for-args-and-kwargs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) springs to mind for the `func` argument.

As for `*args` - whilst it can be type hinted, I'd question the value of doing so. After all, it's an arbitrary set of *positional arguments*.

However, if you insist on doing so, then `*args` is of type [`typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple)