# Is there a way to wrap the elements of a variadic type in Python?

Tags: python, types, typing

Here's a trivial example of what I'm looking for. Suppose you want a function that returns an iterable of the same type as x for each argument x to the function. So without type signatures, it looks like this;

```
def trivial(*args):
    return tuple([[arg] for arg in args])
```

How would I type a function like this? Is this supported?

Comment: Is this the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031928/type-annotations-for-args-and-kwargs?

Comment: I don't think you can type that function safely.  I'd rethink the interface to make the typing easier, personally -- iterables of mixed types are awkward to work with in general.

Comment: @Samwise Is it just me, or have questions about type annotations exploded in the last few months? Did something happen recently to make everyone want to express complex type relationships?

Comment: @JamieDoornbos That question is about type hints for the arguments, this is about the return value.

Comment: The kind of type relationship that this wants to express is something like `Tuple[A, B, C, ...] -> Tuple[List[A], List[B], List[C], ...]` which is something I don't think you can express even without bringing the normal difficulties of typing `*args` into it.