# Why can't you use Dict[str, Any] or Mapping[str, Any] to type **kwargs? How are you supposed to type it?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pyright

I am currently trying to learn how to best include types in my Python code, but I'm a little perplexed on how to properly type `**kwargs` in my function signatures.

A minimal example of what I currently have:

```py
def foo(name: str, **kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> int:

    modified_name: str = f'This is an example for {name}!'

    return some_other_func(modified_name, **kwargs)


def bar(id_number: int, **kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> int:

    name: str = some_func(id_number)
    
    return foo(name, number=id_number, **kwargs)
```

**What I expect to happen**: Since `foo` does not specify the `number` keyword argument, I expect it to get collected into `foo`'s `kwargs`, which is essentially a `Dict[str, Any]`. Since "int" is an "Any" type I should have no complaints about typing.

**What really happens**: At runtime `number` is collected into `foo`'s `kwarg`s and `some_other_func` can safely pull out the `number` keyword argument. However, mypy (version 1.1.1) complains with the following

`error: Argument "number" to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Dict[str, Any]"`

A similar complaint from pyright (version 1.1.292):

`Argument of type "int" cannot be assigned to parameter "number" of type "Dict[str, Any]" in function "foo"  "int" is incompatible with "Dict[str, Any]"`

Is this expected behavior? Should I expect type checkers to complain if I am passing keyword arguments the direct callee doesn't have in the function signature?

Continuing this I thought okay, I will just add `number` as a key in `kwargs` directly (whether this is good practice I'm not sure, but this is besides the point), so this way I will certainly be passing a `Dict[str, Any]`. This is essentially what I tried:

```py
def bar(id_number: int, **kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> int:

    name: str = some_func(id_number)
    
    kwargs[number] = id_number
    
    return foo(name, **kwargs)
```

But now I get the error (from mypy):

`error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", target has type "Dict[str, Any]"`

Similarly from pyright:

`Argument of type "int" cannot be assigned to parameter "__value" of type "Dict[str, Any]" in function "__setitem__"  "int" is incompatible with "Dict[str, Any]"`

But this is even more confusing, why do they seem to imply I'm assigning to `kwargs` when really I'm assigning to a key in `kwargs`?

Does it then mean I'm supposed to be typing the values *inside* of `kwargs` then?

If instead I type `kwargs` as "Union[int, Dict[str, Any]]" I get no issue. So this seems to confirm the question. But why the different behavior? Is it simply convenience that we should know `kwargs` is a mapping, so avoid the extra typing wrap? But I don't see this stated anywhere and I'm not 100% convinced I am correct on how this works.

Finally, I've also tried using `Mapping[str, Any]` intead of `Dict[str, Any]`, but it has same issue.

tl;dr: `kwargs` is a dictionary containing keywords not specified by the function signature and it can be accessed and modified like a `Dict[str, Any]`. Why can't I type it like one? How should I really type it?

Comment: `dict[str, Any]` represents `dict[key_type, value_type]`. `typing.Dict` has been deprecated since python 3.9.

Comment: You're supposed to use `typing.Unpack[<typing.TypedDict subclass>]`. See [PEP 692](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you using `**kwargs`,  the key is always going to be a string. For type-checking the value of that key, you only need to type check one possible value for the key.
For more detail, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37032111/19916174) question and it's answer.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers just to link to another (already solved) question. Use "flag as duplicate" action on the post instead.

Comment: I see now my question is mostly a duplicate and I should have inspected the post you linked more clearly. The fact that I only have to specify the keys was the point of confusion for me. Thank you!