# Is it possible for `**kwargs` to have one type for a specific name, and another type for all other names?

Tags: python, typing

I have a function like this:

```py
def foo(*, x: bool, **kwargs: int) -> None:
    ...
```

If there is an argument `x`, it must be a `bool`. Any other named argument must be an `int`.

Other people will write functions that call `foo`, and I would like them to be able to pass along `x` and the `kwargs`. Currently, that means that every function which calls `foo()` will have to explicitly pass `x`, in addition to the `kwargs`, like this:

```py
def f(a: str, b: str, x: bool, **kwargs: int) -> None:
    print(a + b)
    foo(x=x, **kwargs)
```

What I would like to do is define a type for the `**kwargs` which makes it unnecessary to explicitly specify `x` in each of the functions.

Using `Unpack` gets part of the way there, but `Unpack` requires all names to be known and listed in the `TypedDict`. The code below doesn't work, but I wish I could do something like this, where `_other_` magically means any name that's not listed above in the `TypedDict`:

```py
class FooKwargs(TypedDict):
    x: bool
    _other_: int

def foo(**kwargs: Unpack[FooKwargs]) -> None:
    ...

def f(a: str, b: str, **kwargs: Unpack[FooKwargs]) -> None:
    print(a + b)
    foo(**kwargs)
```

Another possibility that I wish would work is something like this, but it doesn't work because `Unpack` only accept `TypedDict`s -- it won't accept a `Union`, or a `dict[str, int]`:

```py
class FooKnownKwargs(TypedDict):
    x: bool


FooKwargs = Union[FooKnownKwargs, dict[str, int]]


def foo(**kwargs: Unpack[FooKwargs]) -> None:
    ...


def f(a: str, b: str, **kwargs: Unpack[FooKwargs]) -> None:
    print(a + b)
    foo(**kwargs)
```

Again, what I'm looking for is:

- A type for `**kwargs` so that I don't need to explicitly specify an `x` parameter in the signatures of `foo` and `f`.
- In `f()`, I don't want to explicitly pass `x` to `foo()`. I would like `x` to go along with the `**kwargs` automatically, but also keep the type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031928/type-annotations-for-args-and-kwargs

Comment: The **entire point** of using `kwargs` in that way, without separating out `x` specially, is to indicate that you **do not care** about tracking details at that level. That was true before annotations were added to the language, before annotations became widely used for third-party type-checking tools, and is still true now.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that may have been true in the past, but the addition of `Unpack` shows that it is not the case anymore. https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/

Comment: I think that something like your "half-magic" attribute could be a viable addition to PEP692, consider bringing it up on its discussion topic ("Accepted" status is not "Final", new detail can be added). There was a sort of similar addition to `dataclasses` in 3.10: `KW_ONLY` constant that makes following attributes kw-only in constructor, so a precedent exists. It may also work as a metaclass argument (so that you do smth like `class MyArgs(TypedDict, rest=int)`).

Comment: Thanks, I commented on PEP692 here: https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-692-using-typeddict-for-more-precise-kwargs-typing/17314/87