# Disallow Python Variadic Arguments

Tags: python, continuous-integration, lint

Is there any linting tool in existence that is capable of disallowing the use of variadic arguments in functions (*args, **kwargs), without needing to write a plugin?

Comment: Why would you want that? Variadic arguments are a common and necessary feature.

Comment: Its for a codebase that will serve as an API, so I want all args listed out and defined. I've seen engineers massively abuse variadic arguments in this setting, making the API's very hard to use and understand.

Comment: So... write the API such that it does not have any functions with variadic args.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: The difficulty is that there will actually be multiple of these API's written over the course of several years with a team of engineers. I need checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, whilst absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. I did a pretty thorough search for this a while ago and found nothing. [ruffs linter](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/linter/) pulls in rules from most of the major linters, (pflakes, flake8, black, isort) it doesn't have a rule for it.

I know the pain of this... I've seen some code written by well meaning untrained programmers that  `**kwargs` as the signature for every function to avoid having to change the signature of their functions, but you end up with code that is impossible to reason about or type check.

Unfortunately, there are many valid/unavoidable use cases for them, that a hard "no" by a linter hasn't become a thing.

In our case we solved this issue by first doing a bunch of education/training and then by using [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) with [-no-untyped-defs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-disallow-untyped-defs) to enforce typing of function definitions. [The difficulty of typing of **kwargs and *args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031928/type-annotations-for-args-and-kwargs?noredirect=1&lq=1) was  enough "encouragement" to cement the change.

Comment: Exactly. The **kwagrs abuse is precisely what I'm trying to prevent. Perhaps I will just have to add flake8 to my CI, and write a plugin (I'm currently using ruff, which doesn't support plugins at the moment).